# How do I get started implementing the grooveshark api

Tags: php, json, api, grooveshark

I have a client who wants me to implement the Grooveshark API into his site to be used as a fully fledged music system. It will be able to play, pause and skip songs from playlists that the user creates and and tracks the user favourites. So the user will have the ability to search for a track, add to playlist, favourite, play and the reverse of all these actions.

My question is. How do I get started. So I have the API (well the public version http://www.apishark.com as I am waiting for the full version to be sent to me). I look at the API and I just see what appears to me to be short snippets of code.

Is there some kind of a default way to implement an API, what do I need to know, how do I go about this task?

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Here](http://codecanyon.net/item/grooveshark-api-library-class/234352) you can find a php class to ease your work. It's not free but it's extremely cheap, and if you are not able to sort our how to use a standard REST api, and you have to do this for a work, maybe it's worth the price.

Or you can try [here](http://code.google.com/p/groovesharkapi-php/updates/list) for a free class, but I never tried it and you have to use git to download the last version. I believe it's still under development, though.

Or, [here](http://code.google.com/p/grooveshark-scripts/source/browse/trunk/GroovesharkAPI-python/sharky/sharky.py?r=7) you find a free python script that maybe it's easy to convert in PHP. Same [here](http://search.cpan.org/~miorel/WWW-Grooveshark-0.02/lib/WWW/Grooveshark.pm) for a perl module.